# AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'common'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-2

I tried to execute some project. But I've got an `attribute error`.
I checked my Tensorflow and Keras version.

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.3.1
Name: Keras
Version: 2.4.3
Summary: Deep Learning for humans
python 3.8.2
```

The code is here.

```
self.dim_ordering = K.common.image_dim_ordering()
```

Error message:

```
self.dim_ordering = K.common.image_dim_ordering()
AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'common'
```

Is it okay to use  `K.image_data_format()` instead of `k.common.image_dim_ordering()` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. It is okay to use `k.image_data_format()`

In Keras v2 the method has been renamed to image_data_format